# Мокать __call в phpunit

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit

### Есть тест и тестируемый класс:

```
class SomeClass
{
   public function __constructor($vars)
   {
      $this->vars = $vars;
   }

   public function __call($funcName, $args)
   {
      //что то делает
   }
}

class AnotherClass
{
   public static function doSomething(SomeClass $obj, $var)
   {
      $obj->setVar($var);
   }
}

class Framework_MockObjectTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
   public function setUp()
   {
      // это изменять нельзя
      $this->mock = $this->getMockBuilder('SomeClass')
         ->disableOriginalConstructor()
         ->getMock();
   }

   public function testDoSomting()
   {
      $this->mock->expects($this->once())
           ->method('setVar')
           ->with('test');

      AnotherClass::doSomething($this->mock, 'test');
   }
}
```

### Проблема:

Как написать тест который проверит что вызывался метод `setVar` которого по настоящему не существует, так как вместо него работает `__call`.

### Ограничения конкретно моей задачи:

- Нельзя изменить создание мока, например так `$this->mock =
  $this->getMock('SomeClass', ['setVar'])`;
- Нужно обязано использовать `$this->mock`, тоесть создать в тесте другой
  мок нельзя.
- Невозможно использовать `enableProxyingToOriginalMethods` так как у меня есть конструктор
- Запрещено мокать `__call` так

  ```
  $mock->expects($this->once())
      ->method('__call')
      ->with(
          $this->equalTo('setVar'),
          $this->equalTo(['test'])
      );
  ```

### Как пробовал решить:

- использовать `enableProxyingToOriginalMethods` - но конструктор мешает
- в существующий мок добавлять методы, а после теста удалять - класс мока не дает таких возможностей, или я не нашел
- расширить поведение создания мока таким образом что бы мокать все методы кроме указанных - тут информации очень много нужно пересмотреть что бы только понять, возможно ли это вообще
- написать универсальный стаб на метод `__call` что бы вызывал реальный метод `__call` - сама идея звучит неправильно, и реализовать несмог

Comment: Просто не нужно использовать `__call` вот именно по этой причине скрытия реального функционала. `__call` - он для всяких сложных случаев, но не для повседневной разработки.

Comment: @Etki __call реализует некий патерн, по моему реестр, без этой магии все будет довольно печально :). И потому я подумываю расширить функционал phpunit что бы все разработчики могли прозрачно мокать несуществующие методы касающиеся этого магического функционала.

Comment: пчально, как видите, наоборот, с ним

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Написал чистое решение данной задачи без использования `phpunit`. Самую сложную часть работы по адаптации под `phpunit` оставляю вам :)

Модель:

```
class CallModel
{
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        //Что-то делаем в коде проекта
    }
}
```

Мок:

```
class CallModelMock extends CallModel
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $calls = [];

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $checkingMethodName;

    /**
     * @param $name
     * @param $arguments
     */
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($name, $this->calls)) {
            $this->calls[$name]['times']++;
            $this->calls[$name]['calledArguments'][] = $arguments;
        } else {
            $times = 1;
            $calledArguments = $arguments;
            $this->calls[$name] = [
                'times' => $times,
                'calledArguments' => $calledArguments
            ];
        }

        return parent::__call($name, $arguments);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $methodName
     * @param int $times
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function shouldHaveReceived($methodName, $times = 1)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($methodName, $this->calls)) {
            if ($this->calls[$methodName]['times'] === $times) {
                $this->checkingMethodName = $methodName;

                return $this;
            }
        }

        throw new \Exception('notExistingMethod does\'t called');
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $arguments
     *
     * @return $this
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function withArgs($arguments)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($this->checkingMethodName, $this->calls)) {
            foreach ($this->calls[$this->checkingMethodName]['calledArguments'] as $calledArguments) {
                if ($calledArguments === $arguments) {
                    return $this;
                }
            }
        }

        throw new \Exception('notExistingMethod does\'t called with expected arguments');
    }
}
```

Тест:

```
class CallMockTest
{
    /**
     * @var CallModelMock
     */
    private $mock;

    public function _before()
    {
        $this->mock = new CallModelMock();
    }

    public function testMockCall()
    {
        $this->mock->notExistingMethod();
        $this->mock->notExistingMethod();

        $callTimes = 2;
        $this->mock->shouldHaveReceived('notExistingMethod', $callTimes);
    }

    /**
     * @expectedException \Exception
     * @expectedExceptionMessage notExistingMethod does't called
     */
    public function testWrongMockCall()
    {
        $this->mock->notExistingMethod();
        $this->mock->notExistingMethod();

        $callTimes = 1;
        $this->mock->shouldHaveReceived('notExistingMethod', $callTimes);
    }

    public function testMockCallWithArguments()
    {
        $argument = 'someArgument';
        $this->mock->notExistingMethod($argument);
        $this->mock->shouldHaveReceived('notExistingMethod')->withArgs($argument);
    }

    /**
     * @expectedException \Exception
     * @expectedExceptionMessage notExistingMethod does't called with expected arguments
     */
    public function testWringMockCallWithArguments()
    {
        $this->mock->notExistingMethod('correct argument');
        $this->mock->shouldHaveReceived('notExistingMethod')->withArgs('incorrect argument');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

метод в моке можно динамически создать/удалить с помощью [runkit](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.runkit.php)

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.